# Обрезать изображение PHP не работает

Tags: php

подскажите почему не работает код?

```js
<?php
    require "db.php";   
    $login = $_SESSION['logged_user']->login;
    $settings = R::findOne('users', 'WHERE `login`=?', [$login]);
if ($_FILES && $_FILES["file"]["error"] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK){
    if($_FILES['file']['size'] < 5242880){
        if($_FILES['file']['type'] == ('image/jpeg' || 'image/png') ){
            
            $Image = imagecreatefrompng($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);

            $widthImg = imagesx($Image);
            $heightImg = imagesy($Image);

            if ($widthImg < $heightImg){
                $ReadyImage = imagecrop($Image, ['x' => 0, 'y' => ($heightImg - $widthImg)/2, 'width' => $widthImg, 'height' => $widthImg]);
            }else{
                $ReadyImage = imagecrop($Image, ['x' => ($widthImg - $heightImg)/2, 'y' => 0, 'width' => $heightImg, 'height' => $heightImg]);
            }
            $filepath = "ava/" . $settings->id;
            move_uploaded_file($ReadyImage, $filepath);  /* Загружаем файл по указанному пути */

        }else{
            /* Учитывая accept в html, скорей всего попытка на инъекцию, начисление штрафных баллов в дальнейшем возможнен бан(ещё не реализована)*/        }
    }else{
        echo 202; /* big size */
    }
}
?>
```

Перестало работать после добавления вот этого кода:

```js
$Image = imagecreatefrompng($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);

            $widthImg = imagesx($Image);
            $heightImg = imagesy($Image);

            if ($widthImg < $heightImg){
                $ReadyImage = imagecrop($Image, ['x' => 0, 'y' => ($heightImg - $widthImg)/2, 'width' => $widthImg, 'height' => $widthImg]);
            }else{
                $ReadyImage = imagecrop($Image, ['x' => ($widthImg - $heightImg)/2, 'y' => 0, 'width' => $heightImg, 'height' => $heightImg]);
            }
```

Comment: Надо воспользоваться отладкой! А также включить отображение ошибок!

Comment: Ошибка в строке move_uploaded_file. Путь правильный, значить что-то не так с обрезкой изображения

Comment: А мне вот эта строчка понравилась `$_FILES['file']['type'] == ('image/jpeg' || 'image/png')`. Человек использует синтаксический сахар ещё до его введения в php. Мощно

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в PHP коде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701142/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-php-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5)

Comment: Насчёт синтаксического сахара объясните пожалуйста, PHP серьезно не поддерживает такую запись?

Comment: `('image/jpeg' || 'image/png')` вам вернёт bool (true). Дальше вы сравниваете строку `'some text' == true` что в свою очередь вернёт bool (true). Потому что сравнение на самом деле выглядеть так `(bool) 'some text' == true` или `true == true `

Comment: Ну и к слову. Вы допускаете тип `image/jpeg` при этом делаете `imagecreatefrompng`. PNG, Карл!

Comment: Тут я с Вами согласен, но вы написали это на тот момент времени когда уже был выложен новый код где эти тупыши устранены, посмотрите ответ

Comment: Мне правда интересно Ваше мнение насчет нового способа проверки формата)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот итоговый(рабочий) код:

```js
<?php
    require "db.php";   
    $login = $_SESSION['logged_user']->login;
    $settings = R::findOne('users', 'WHERE `login`=?', [$login]);
if ($_FILES && $_FILES["file"]["error"] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK){
    if($_FILES['file']['size'] < 5242880){
        if (in_array($_FILES['file']['type'], array('image/jpeg', 'image/png'))){
            $filepath = "ava/" . $settings->id;
            if($_FILES['file']['type'] == 'image/jpeg'){
                $Image = imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
            }else{
                $Image = imagecreatefrompng($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
            }
            $widthImg = imagesx($Image);
            $heightImg = imagesy($Image);
            if ($widthImg != $heightImg){
                $ReadyImage = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
                if ($widthImg < $heightImg){
                    $ReadyImage = imagecrop($Image, ['x' => 0, 'y' => ($heightImg - $widthImg)/2, 'width' => $widthImg, 'height' => $widthImg]);
                }
                if ($widthImg > $heightImg){
                    $ReadyImage = imagecrop($Image, ['x' => ($widthImg - $heightImg)/2, 'y' => 0, 'width' => $heightImg, 'height' => $heightImg]);
                }            
                if($_FILES['file']['type'] == 'image/jpeg'){
                    imagejpeg($ReadyImage, $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
                }else{
                    imagepng($ReadyImage, $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
                }
            }
            
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $filepath); 
            echo 101;
        }else{
        /* Учитывая accept в html, скорей всего попытка на инъекцию, начисление штрафных баллов в дальнейшем возможнен бан(ещё не реализована)*/        
        }
    }else{
        echo 202; /* big size */
    }
}
?>
```